# What shared state distributed systems exist which can handle objects in the native language?

Tags: distributed-cache, shared-state

As far as I know there is Terracotta and Maglev. Are there any others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much every big vendor got one, plus a handful of independent vendors:

- memcached [1] — ubiquitous, community-driven;
- Infinispan [2] — backed by JBoss, open-source;
- Velocity [3] — commercial (Microsoft), in beta, .NET only;
- Gemfire [4] — commercial (VMWare)
- Coherence [5] — commercial (Oracle)
- GigaSpaces XAP [6] — commercial
- ScaleOut [7] — commercial
- Terracotta [8] — commercial

Note that there is a pretty thin line between state sharing solutions and distributed caching solutions. I only listed the ones that keep the state in main memory, which are often dubbed "data grids" on the street.

Hope this helps.

- [1] memcached.org
- [2] jboss.org/infinispan
- [3] blogs.msdn.com/b/velocity/
- [4] www.gemstone.com/products/gemfire
- [5] www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html
- [6] gigaspaces.com
- [7] www.scaleoutsoftware.com/products/scaleout-stateserver/
- [8] www.terracotta.org

Comment: I'm receiving a spam haiku when trying to post links. Argh.

Answer (score 2):

**[memcache](http://memcached.org/)** : many major sites use it, Google AppEngine included. There are bindings to it for everything under the sun (pretty much ;-)

Comment: My mistake, I worded the question badly, but you were right, memcached is a shared memory system :)

Answer (score 2):

[Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is probably the most heavily used one (as their biggest user Facebook shares 28TB of RAM with it at the moment).

Comment: My mistake, I worded the question badly, but you were right, memcached is a shared memory system :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [MemCached](http://memcached.org/), there is [Velocity](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B24C3708-EEFF-4055-A867-19B5851E7CD2&displaylang=en) from Microsoft.

Comment: I researched velocity, but it seems to be just a research lab project and not much info on it. Will it ever see the light of day?

Comment: Microsoft are promoting it, so guess so?

Comment: Ok, thanks. When I get time I'll download it and give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned [MagLev](http://MagLev.GemStone.Com/), there's obviously also [GemStone/S](http://GemStone.Com/products/gemstone/) on top of which MagLev is built, and [GemFire](http://GemStone.Com/products/gemfire/), their JVM/.NET/C++ product.